# echo 2 arrays to 1 table

Tags: php, sql, arrays, echo, html-table

I am holding 2 arrays of SQL results: `$result` and `$result1` (for the example it is the same queries).

I need to add the code that: `if flag = 1` I want that rows in `$result1` will be echo under the rows of the table that I did echo to the `$result`.

In the table will be the rows of `$result` and `if flag = 1` in the same table will be also the rows of `$result1`.

```
$query = "select Username,First_Name from users";
$result = mysql_query($query) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error()); 

$query1 = "select Username,First_Name from users";
$result1 = mysql_query($query1) or die('Query failed: ' . mysql_error());
$flag = 0;

echo '<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FF66AE66"><tr align="center">
<td><b>Username</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td></tr>';
    while($first = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$first["Username"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$first["First_Name"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
    } // end While
```

Comment: You're using mysql. Mysql is deprecated and no longer supported. If you can, make time to update to mysqli or PDO :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo '<table align="center" border="1" cellpadding="5" cellspacing="5" style="border-collapse: collapse; background-color: #FF66AE66"><tr align="center">
<td><b>Username</b></td><td><b>First Name</b></td><td></tr>';
    while($first = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$first["Username"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$first["First_Name"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
    } // end While
if($flag == 1){
    while($last= mysql_fetch_array($result1)){
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>".$last["Username"]."</td>";
                echo "<td>".$last["First_Name"]."</td>";
                echo "</tr>";       
            } // end While
    }
```

Comment: *"Try this:"* - Actually... without an explanation, having said something like *"Here, give this baby a whirl!"* would have been more exciting ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can do two loops, but I think you should find a solution using SQL, that gives you a proper result set. Anyway:

```
while($first = mysql_fetch_array($result)){
    while($second = mysql_fetch_array($second)){
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td>".$first["Username"]."</td>";
        echo "<td>".$first["First_Name"]."</td>";
        echo "</tr>";       
        if($first['flag'] == 1) {
            echo "<tr>";
            echo "<td>".$second["Username"]."</td>";
            echo "<td>".$second["First_Name"]."</td>";
            echo "</tr>";
        }
    }
} /
```